# Python return time performance time.clock()

Tags: python, performance, time, return

I have the following code where I want to measure time performance.

```
import time

def fibonacci(n):
    t0 = time.clock()
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        a = fibonacci(n-1)
        b = fibonacci(n-2)
    return a + b, time.clock()
```

When I run it returns `Type error: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple`
How can I return result of the function together with time performance please? What am I missing here?

Comment: `a` and `b` are results of your function, you're returning a tuple... Just time the main fibonacci call from _outside_ the function.

Comment: You should not use `time.clock`. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.clock): "time.clock() ... Deprecated since version 3.3: .... use perf_counter() or process_time() instead, depending on your requirements"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the function itself to return the time, you have to remember that this is a recursive function that calls itself, so you have to account for (and probably discard) the inner calls timing results. Also you have to edit **all** `return` statements:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    t0 = time.clock()
    if n == 0:
        return 0, time.clock() - t0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1, time.clock() - t0
    else:
        a, _ign = fibonacci(n-1)
        b, _ign = fibonacci(n-2)
    return a + b, time.clock() - t0
```

Another approach would be to measure the time **outside** the function, that way you don't have to modify the function at all:

```
 t0 = time.clock()
 fibonacci(some_number) # call the original function without timing
 time_taken = time.clock() - t0
```

Comment: On windows, the first call to `time.clock()` starts the timer counting from 0 so the `- t0` isn't necessary (although it would be bad style to omit as functionality would change if you moved to another O.S.)

Answer (score 2):

`a` and `b` are results of your function, you're returning a tuple... Just time the main fibonacci call from *outside* the function, in a function wrapper for instance:

```
def time_fibonacci(n):
    start = time.clock()
    result = fibonacci(n)
    # return a tuple: result + cpu time
    return result, time.clock() - start
```

and fixed fibonacci itself (without the clocking):

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        a = fibonacci(n-1)
        b = fibonacci(n-2)
    return a + b
```